# throw exception through mbean operation

Tags: java, exception, jmx

What is the proper exception handling strategy for MBean operations?  Some of these operations can fail (e.g. drop a user who isn't connected) and an exception should be reported, but I don't know how my exceptions can percolate up to the JMX layer.  My best idea is C-style return codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the intent of [javax.management.MBeanException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanException.html), which is declared as thrown from [MBeanServerConnection.invoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html#invoke%28javax.management.ObjectName,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29). To quote from the JavaDoc:

> Represents "user defined" exceptions thrown by MBean methods in the
>   agent. It "wraps" the actual "user defined" exception thrown.

So rather than return cryptic integer codes, (or BigDecimal if the bigger the better ;) ) just trap the "business exception", create a new MBeanException using the business exception and throw it. Provided your business exception is serializable and present in the classpath of the caller, the caller should be able to unwrap the JMX exception and get to the business exception.

If either of those assumptions is not true, just create a message based on the business exception class name and message and create an MBeanException from a new Exception (so you get a stack trace) and your new error message.

Comment: Is there any way to get this without actually...umm...catching it and re-throwing it? Like "give me all errors, man!"